# Getting models variable name in razor editor templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to use generate IDs depending on the models variable name.

I have two models

```
public class ConceptViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string EnglishContent { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class InputDataCollectionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ConceptModel Definition { get; set; }
    public ConceptModel Publication { get; set; }
    public bool Exist { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EditorTemplates for ConceptViewModel:

```
@model Models.ConceptViewModel

<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</td>                
    <td hidden>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Content, (@Model.Exist ? null : (object)new { @disabled = "disabled" }))
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnglishContent)
    </td>
    <td hidden>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Instructions)</td>   
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openEditor('UNIQUE_NAME_DEPENDING_ON_MODEL_NAME');">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

and the view:

```
@model Models.InputDataCollectionViewModel    

<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                    <tbody>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Definition)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication)                            
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot></tfoot>
                </table>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        }
    }
```

which generates html containing:

```
<label class="control-label" for="Definition">
<input id="Definition_Content" name="Definition.Content" type="text" value="" />
<input id="Definition_EnglishContent" name="Definition.EnglishContent" type="text" value="" />
<input id="Definition_Instructions" name="Definition.Instructions" type="text" value="..." />
```

and the same for the other ConceptViewModels. So from this I can easily reference it because of the unique IDs (Definition_*, Publication_* and so forth for other inputs I have elsewhere).

Now my question is, how would I get the strings containg "Definition", "Publication" so I could use it with the generated buttons. What I want is:

```
openEditor('Definition');
openEditor('Publication');
```

in the onclick.

Comment: `openEditor('@(nameof(Model.Definition))')`?

Comment: The openEditor() is in the Editor Template, so it only has access to ConceptViewModel not InputDataCollectionViewModel which containt Definition

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find the solution. The Html helper @Html.IdFor(m => m)

Comment: This will give you the HTML `id` attribute, *not* the "variable name" as requested in the question.

Comment: Well as far as I know the `id` is generated based on the name and the helper does exactly what I need. Do you know of a better solution?

Comment: Depends on what you are *actually* trying to do.  Your question asks for variable name, then you immediately state *"generate IDs depending on the models variable name"*.  So you only need the variable name to generate an ID?  **That's an XY Problem**.  Your actual question seems to be that you want an ID, which `@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Property)` will give you.

Comment: I was after either one since they seem to be the same. The `id` was already generated for the input boxes and I needed to get the first part of that `id` for calling my script (since the second part of the `id` (.Content, .EnglishContent and .Instructions) is static). I probably should have worded the question better.

Comment: To be clear, they're not the same.  Especially when you have nested properties and/or arrays.  `@Html.IdFor(m => m.Definition.Name) != nameof(m.Definition.Name)`